# How to remove grid column padding in Semantic UI?

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI grids, I have two columns and they have padding in between them. I have a padding which is good for most cases but I want to remove it in this case, how can I achieve this?

[image]

I want both the menu to be attached.

Answer (score 1):

Without the code I can only assume you're talking about the two areas titled Shareito. If you want to remove the space between them without messing up the padding layout of the whole page you could add a negative margin, for example:

```
.pnl1 {
    margin-right: -15px;
}
.pnl2 {
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

there are many other ways of doing this be it playing with the padding and margins, making the position absolute, etc etc... experiment.

Comment: I thought there would a default way out of it, without adding the css myself. And yes this can always be done, thanks.